Dishwasher Intermittent Leaks
Overall our dishwasher works totally fine. The dishes come out clean, no issues there. There is no funky odor coming from the machine.
But it leaks! And not in an easy to find sort of way, or even easy to predict. It leaks sometimes, and never when it's actually running. The leaks always occur sometime after the machine is done running. I'll have unloaded it and left it and then come back an hour later and there is a small puddle under the thing. Stranger still is the water that leaks out seems to be clean water, not soiled water from the wash itself. It appears the leak is happening at the very bottom of the unit underneath, there is a small metal plate that looks almost like a drip pan that is rusted. Not sure how to add photos here but I have a pic of this piece.
Things I have done:

Cleaned the filter from the inside,
Took the dishwasher out and checked the inlet valve, completely clean
Took out the drain hose and checked for clogs, no clogs
Sighed exasperatedly

I do have a couple photos of the underside that pretty clearly show the rusted piece, but I have no idea how to add photos to this thing.

It could be a seal or bearing on the shaft at the bottom that leaking clean rince water.  We need the pictures. Edit them into your question with the image key.

use the mountains and moon icon to upload pics. it's the 6th from the left  above you post when you edit it.

Apparently new users don't have "rights" to upload photos.  You could put them on imgur or somewhere and link to them here.  Can you remove the rusty part to look inside better?
